# How to extend typo3 image editor to add another format 16:11?

Tags: php, typo3

How to add more options in "Image manipulation" editor in typo3 FAL Image
Please find below Image for detail description

[image: IMAGE EDITOR]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Createn an extension and install it. Create the file `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_reference.php`. This is where you can add ratios to the cropping tool:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['columns']['crop']['config'] = array(
    'type' => 'imageManipulation',
    'allowedExtensions' => 'jpg',
    'ratios' => array(
        '1.7777777777777777' => '16:9',
        '1.3333333333333333' => '4:3',
        '0.71428571428571' => '5:7',
        '1' => '1:1',
        'NaN' => 'Free',
    ),
);
```